# How to locate text input by name using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm a selenium newbie and just trying to learn the basics. I have a simple CherryPy webapp that takes a first name and last name as input:

My Webapp:

```
<p>
    <label></label>
    <input name="first_name"></input>
    <br></br>
</p>
<p>
    <label></label>
    <input name="last_name"></input>
    <br></br>
</p>
```

In my python console I have:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://localhost:8080')
```

The page loads fine in FF but I'm a little lost on how to get text into the 'first_name' and 'last_name' text boxes. I see examples where you do something like `inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("n")` and then `inputElement.send_keys('my_first_name')` but I don't have an id...just a `name`. Do I need to add stuff to my web page? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`find_element_by_name`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html#locating-by-name):

```
driver.find_element_by_name('first_name').send_keys("my_first_name")
driver.find_element_by_name('last_name').send_keys("my_last_name")
```

Comment: It happens to the best of us :)